# apt-get -f install

Tags: 12.04, apt

I'm trying to `apt-get -f install` on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. I get the following error message:

```
After this operation, 157 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 122731 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.5.0-34-generic (from .../linux-image-3.5.0-34-generic_3.5.0-34.55~precise1_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-34-generic_3.5.0-34.55~precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-34-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-34-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-34-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.5.0-34-generic_3.5.0-34.55~precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My primary disk isn't full - however, my boot partition is only ~100MB. Is apt-get trying to install stuff to /boot? It does mention trying to do something to ./boot/vmlinux[...]

I get a longer but eventually similar error trying to `apt-get -f upgrade` as well. What's going on?

`uname -r` yields simply `3.5.0-31-generic`
`dpkg -l | grep linux-image`yields this:

```
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-28-generic      3.5.0-28.48~precise1         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-30-generic      3.5.0-30.51~precise1         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.5.0-31-generic      3.5.0-31.52~precise1         Linux kernel image for version 3.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic-lts-quantal   3.5.0.32.39                  Generic Linux kernel image
```

Which I'm guessing means I have a certain number of kernels that I could purge?
 But when I try to apt-get purge, it asks me to run apt-get -f install because of an unmet dependency...

And yeah, I checked disk space and /dev/sda (which is /boot/) is 100% full. This install has been running ~40 days total, and has been booted once (today)I I did some research before deciding on a /boot size, and 100MB seemed to be a pretty reasonable size. What's going on?

I tried running apt-get clean, autoclean, autoremove, and manually purging a given kernel. I keep getting

```
 linux-image-generic-lts-quantal : Depends: linux-image-3.5.0-32-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: run df -h command and paste your result friend

Comment: Yes, `apt-get` is trying to upgrade your kernel (where some files will reside in `/boot`), but you don't have enough space, probably due to older kernels still installed. What's the output of `uname -r` and `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`? [Edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/315275/edit) and paste their outputs.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove` and try again.